# Square API CreateCustomer not showing up in Dashboard

Tags: square-connect

I've created several customers (note, with the test token) via the API however I expected them to be listed on the [dashboard](https://squareup.com/dashboard/customers/directory).

Are customers created with a live token added to the dashboard?

It would be easier for me to delete my test customers via the dashboard then coding a bunch of extra stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not see sandbox customers in Dashboard, but your production customers will show like normal.